# The pointwise limit of increasing functions on $[0,1]$ is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_{n}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function on $[0,1]$.  Suppose that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges pointwise to a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Prove first that $f$ is an increasing function on $[0,1]$, and then show that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably by increasing you mean what is sometimes called non-decreasing. For we can easily find (strictly) increasing functions that converge pointwise to the identically $0$ function. Just let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$.

Now we prove that the pointwise limit of non-decreasing functions is non-decreasing. Suppose to the contrary that $f(a) \gt f(b)$ for some $a$ and $b$, where $0\le a\lt b\le 1$. Let $\epsilon=f(a)-f(b)$. Since the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$, the is an $A$ such that if $n\gt A$ then $|f_n(a)-f(a)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Similarly, there is a $B$ such that if $n\gt B$ then $|f_n(b)-f(b)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Let $N=\max(A,B)$. If $n\gt N$, then we have simultaneously $|f_n(a)-f(a)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $|f_n(b)-f(b)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. It follows that for such an $n$ we have $f_n(a)-f_n(b)\ge \epsilon -\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$, contradicting the fact that $f_n$ is non-decreasing.